# CORS ERROR: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use the "Article Search API" provided by the New York Times to allow my web application to display news articles based on the search results. I followed the tutorial at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Third_party_APIs and used their javascript code as closely as I could. The issue is that when I clicked on the 'submit search' button, my web-developer's console on Firefox showed me the message:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://nyt-prod.apigee.net/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?api-key=(***MY KEY: CENSORED***)&page=0&q=Trump&fq=document_type:(%22article%22)&begin_date=2019-01-01&end_date=2019-01-05. (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed)."
This is where I am getting stuck. I really do not know what is happening here.

The 'Article Search API' is currently using the base URL 'https://nyt-prod.apigee.net/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json', which I did carefully examine. I do not think the base-url has any problem, as can be conjectured based on the error message I got. I also tried to run this on Chrome and was using the Python testing server, but the problem remains.

I am willing to show the entire html file including the javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NY Times API example</title>
    <link href="nytimes.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>NY Times video search</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="controls">
        <form>
          <p>
            <label for="search">Enter a SINGLE search term (required): </label>
            <input type="text" id="search" class="search" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="start-date">Enter a start date (format YYYYMMDD): </label>
            <input type="date" id="start-date" class="start-date" pattern="[0-9]{8}">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="end-date">Enter an end date (format YYYYMMDD): </label>
            <input type="date" id="end-date" class="end-date" pattern="[0-9]{8}">
          </p>
          <p>
            <button class="submit">Submit search</button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="results">
        <nav>
          <button class="prev">Previous 10</button>
          <button class="next">Next 10</button>
        </nav>

        <section>
        </section>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      // Defining a baseURL and key to as part of the request URL
      var baseURL = 'https://nyt-prod.apigee.net/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json';
      var key = 'CENSORED';
      var url;
      // Grab references to all the DOM elements you'll need to manipulate
      var searchTerm = document.querySelector('.search');
      var startDate = document.querySelector('.start-date');
      var endDate = document.querySelector('.end-date');
      var searchForm = document.querySelector('form');
      var submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit');
      var nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');
      var previousBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
      var section = document.querySelector('section');
      var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
      // Hide the "Previous"/"Next" navigation to begin with, as we don't need it immediately
      nav.style.display = 'none';
      // define the initial page number and status of the navigation being displayed
      var pageNumber = 0;
      var displayNav = false;
      // Event listeners to control the functionality
      searchForm.addEventListener('submit', submitSearch);


      function submitSearch(e) {
        pageNumber = 0;
        fetchResults(e);
      }

      function fetchResults(e) {
        // Use preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting:
        e.preventDefault();

        // Assemble the full URL:
        url = baseURL + '?api-key=' + key + '&page=' + pageNumber + '&q=' + searchTerm.value + '&fq=document_type:("article")';

        if (startDate.value !== '') {
          url += '&begin_date=' + startDate.value;
        }

        if (endDate.value !== '') {
          url += '&end_date=' + endDate.value;
        }

        // Use fetch() to make the request to the API
        fetch(url).then(function(result) {
          return result.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
          displayResults(json);
        });

      }

      function displayResults(json) {
        while (section.firstChild) {
          section.removeChild(section.firstChild);
        }

        var articles = json.response.docs;

        if(articles.length === 10) {
          nav.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          nav.style.display = 'none';
        }

        if(articles.length === 0) {
          var para = document.createElement('p');
          para.textContent = 'No results returned.'
          section.appendChild(para);
        } else {
          for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
            var article = document.createElement('article');
            var heading = document.createElement('h2');
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            var para1 = document.createElement('p');
            var para2 = document.createElement('p');
            var clearfix = document.createElement('div');

            var current = articles[i];
            console.log(current);

            link.href = current.web_url;
            link.textContent = current.headline.main;
            para1.textContent = current.snippet;
            para2.textContent = 'Keywords: ';
            for(var j = 0; j < current.keywords.length; j++) {
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.textContent += current.keywords[j].value + ' ';
              para2.appendChild(span);
            }

            if(current.multimedia.length > 0) {
              img.src = 'http://www.nytimes.com/' + current.multimedia[0].url;
              img.alt = current.headline.main;
            }

            clearfix.setAttribute('class','clearfix');

            article.appendChild(heading);
            heading.appendChild(link);
            article.appendChild(img);
            article.appendChild(para1);
            article.appendChild(para2);
            article.appendChild(clearfix);
            section.appendChild(article);
          }
        }
      };
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

But I think the most important lines are as follows:

```
var baseURL = 'https://nyt-prod.apigee.net/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json';
var key = 'CENSORED';
...
...
url = baseURL + '?api-key=' + key + '&page=' + pageNumber + '&q=' + searchTerm.value + '&fq=document_type:("article")';
...
...
fetch(url).then(function(result) {
      return result.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      displayResults(json);
    });
...
...
if(current.multimedia.length > 0) {
          img.src = 'http://www.nytimes.com/' + current.multimedia[0].url;
          img.alt = current.headline.main;
        }
```

The news articles are supposed to show up on the right hand side in blocks arranged in a vertical fashion. With this error, I saw nothing. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: the answer is in the error `Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed` - clearly that site is not configured correctly for CORS as it is issuing multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in its response ... the issue is with the server ... look in your browsers developer tools console - check the response headers you are receiving to confirm

Comment: I am aware of a way to deal with it, as documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMultipleAllowOriginNotAllowed. I do have a hard time understanding what the passage means: "If you have access to the server you can change your implementation to echo back an origin in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. You cannot send back a list of origins, because browsers only accept a value that is either a single origin or null." ... The main issue here is that I do not know what code I should add to my html or javascript to achieve what the document instructs.

Comment: Do you own the server that sends that response?

Comment: No. If you are asking the server I used to run my html on, I used the Python testing server: python3 -m http.server (Am I right in saying that  this is the server that sends the request, instead of the response?) As for the server that the New York Times API runs on, I do not own it.

Comment: I'm speaking about the server that you are trying to access, the request goes to `nyt-prod.apigee.net` and fails because `nyt-prod.apigee.net` responds with multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers ... is that your server?

Comment: No. It is not. It comes from here: https://nyt-devportal.apigee.io/docs/articlesearch-product/1/overview. On the left hand side is a link (/articlesearch.json) to the base url. Do you think I should ask the API developers about this issue?

Comment: have you confirmed that you are indeed receiving two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response headers from them (and it's not some addon you've got on your browser that's responsible, for example)

Comment: I am much more inclined towards believing the former, since I have tried to run my code both on Firefox and on Chrome. They encountered the same issue. I am very inexperienced, though, so I do not even know how to confirm that.

Comment: See my first comment. Developer tools, in your browser,  F12 usually

Comment: I found it (I needed to click on some buttons to reveal the headers). Yes. I received two '*' response headers from them.